# difference between `sr()` and `sniff()` scapy

Tags: http, packet, scapy

i want to know the difference between `sr()` and `sniff()`
i will clear myself:
when i send packets with `sr()` and then print the answer, it's giving me just one packet:

```
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
[(<IP  frag=0 ttl=64 proto=tcp dst=216.58.210.4 |<TCP  sport=37945 dport=http seq=1 ack=1477254816 flags=A |<Raw  load='GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \n\n' |>>>, <IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=40 id=1338 flags= frag=0L ttl=128 proto=tcp chksum=0xe12d src=216.58.210.4 dst=192.168.233.128 options=[] |<TCP  sport=http dport=37945 seq=1477254816 ack=28 dataofs=5L reserved=0L flags=A window=64240 chksum=0x5528 urgptr=0 |<Padding  load='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' |>>>)]
```

but when i do the same with sniff i got alot more packets, and one of them its the packet with the answer i asked:

```
<Ether  dst=00:0c:29:bb:8e:79 src=00:50:56:e9:b8:b1 type=0x800 |<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=537 id=1339 flags= frag=0L ttl=128 proto=tcp chksum=0xdf3b src=216.58.210.4 dst=192.168.233.128 options=[] |<TCP  sport=http dport=37945 seq=1477254816 ack=28 dataofs=5L reserved=0L flags=PA window=64240 chksum=0x98df urgptr=0 options=[] |<Raw  load='HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nCache-Control: private\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nLocation: http://www.google.co.il/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_geSV8u1C6Xb8AeaxJCoDQ\r\nContent-Length: 271\r\nDate: Fri, 22 Jul 2016 11:48:14 GMT\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>302 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF="http://www.google.co.il/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=_geSV8u1C6Xb8AeaxJCoDQ">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n' |>>>>
```

if you will see - the second packet have the html code i asked for (that was with sniffing it.) but wht first not have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sr()` is Send and receive packets. The function sends specific packets and then looks for the response to only those packets

`sniff()` acts as a sniffer and reads all of the traffic on the ethernet line, even if it is not directed towards your IP address or your specific socket that you used to send the original packet. This allows you to see other traffic on the network

Comment: so how can i get the HTTP answer by "sr" and not the Ack message? is it possible?

Comment: with `sr()` you should receive an ACK. Then, send a SYN/ACK, then send the TCP payload

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lsc() in scapy bash to check out all the required commands and their usage.

sr               : Send and receive packets at layer 3

sr1              : Send packets at layer 3 and return only the first answer

srp              : Send and receive packets at layer 2

srp1             : Send and receive packets at layer 2 and return only the first answer

srloop           : Send a packet at layer 3 in loop and print the answer each time

srploop          : Send a packet at layer 2 in loop and print the answer each time

sniff            : Sniff packets

send             : Send packets at layer 3

sendp            : Send packets at layer 2

You can use the sniff(iface ="your interface", filter = "dst aa:bb:cc:dd:ee") to get the packets that you want.
The sniff function has lots of parameters to shortlist the packets.